# Weird issue when comparing dates in php

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I am experiencing an issue when comparing two dates in php.

**The problem:** When comparing 12:00 AM (midnight) to eg 10:00 AM (morning) the following code will not work properly. According to human logic 10:00 AM is later than 12:00 AM. But computers seem not to recognize that.

Is there any way to do this differently?

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Athens');
$today = date("d-m-Y h:i:s A");
$today = date("d-m-Y h:i:s A",strtotime($today));
$max = date('d-m-Y h:i:s A', strtotime("31-12-2015 23:59:00"));
$min = date('d-m-Y h:i:s A', strtotime("14-12-2015 00:00:01"));

if (($today > $min) && ($today < $max)){
    //do something
} else {
    //something else done
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `date()` return String.

From the [manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php#refsect1-function.date-returnvalues):

> #### Return Values
>
> Returns a formatted date string. If a non-numeric value is used for timestamp, FALSE is returned and an E_WARNING level error is emitted.

Basically, what your code trying to do is something like this:

```
if("31-12-2015 23:59:00 PM" < "14-12-2015 00:00:01 AM") {
    .......
}
```

<del>So, PHP will ignore the "AM" or "PM" string, and just compare the numeric value.</del>

**EDIT**: From [comparison operator](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) manual:

> If you compare a number with a string or the comparison involves numerical strings, then each string is [converted to a number](https://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion) and the comparison performed numerically.

So, because PHP convert their value again, then your code is comparing a different value entirely.

---

> Is there any way to do this differently?

Just compare from the `strtotime` value.

```
$today = strtotime("now");
$max = strtotime("31-12-2015 23:59:00");
$min = strtotime("14-12-2015 00:00:01");

if (($today > $min) && ($today < $max)){
        //do something

}else{
        //something else done
}
```

and later format your value again using `date` to AM/PM format (if needed).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `date_create()` & `date_diff()` PHP inbuilt functions, to compare two dates and in your scenario it will help you.

```
$date1 = date_create("2013-03-15"); 
$date2 = date_create("2013-12-12");
$diff = date_diff($date1,$date2);
echo $diff->format("%R%a days");
```

Comment: I don't recommend to mix OOP and procedural style

Answer (score 1):

Try like this..

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Athens');
            $today = date("d-m-Y h:i:s A");                
            $max = date('d-m-Y h:i:s A', strtotime("31-12-2015 23:59:00"));
            $min = date('d-m-Y h:i:s A', strtotime("14-12-2015 00:00:01"));

            if ((strtotime($today) > strtotime($min)) && (strtotime($today) < strtotime($max))){
                    //do something

            }else{
                    //something else done
```

For example:

```
if (strtotime("12:00 AM")>strtotime("10:00 AM")){
 echo "do something";
}else{
 echo "something else done"; 
}
```

//output "something else done";

Comment: `$today = date("d-m-Y h:i:s A");
            $today = date("d-m-Y h:i:s A",strtotime($today));` is so redundant

Comment: Even if it does work the two lines are completely redundant.

Comment: I have removed the one